# Execution Time optimization of Java Algorithm logic

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, array-algorithms

I have developed the below logic but it fails to execute in the given time. Its taking more than 4 seconds for a test data set of 100k numbers. Can someone suggest or optimize it to run within 0.2 seconds for a large data set. The problem statement is as below:

> A radio center receives some signals and needs to classify them
>   according to frequency.
>
> There are standard frequencies known to the center. They have
>   identified
>
> different signals which are to be classified. Given the standard
>   signal frequencies freq_standard and frequencies of signals to be
>   classified freq_signal, can you help the radio center identify them?
>
> A signal X belongs to a standard signal Y if the frequency of X is
>   closer to that of Y than to any other frequency. If it is equidistant
>   from two known frequencies, then the signal with higher frequency is
>   chosen.
>
> Consider, for example, freq_standard = [2, 3, 1, 4, 8] and
>   freq_classify = [1, 5, 6]. Frequencies 1 and 5 belong to standard
>   frequencies 1(index=3) and 4(index=4) respectively. Since 6 is
>   equidistant from two standard frequencies, 4 and 8, choose the higher
>   frequency, 8(index=5). The corresponding classifications are [3, 4,
>   5].

**Function Description:**

Complete the function `classifySignals` in the editor below. The function must return an integer array denoting the classifications of each frequency.

`classifySignals` has two parameters -

- `freq_standard`: an integer array
- `freq_signals`: an integer array

**Input Format:**

The first line of input contains 2 space-separated integers: `n,q`- the number of strings and the number of queries.

The second line contains space-separated integers, the array `freq_standard`.

The next line contains `q` space-separated integers, the array `freq_signals`.

**Constraints:**

- n <= 10<sup>5</sup>
- q <= 10<sup>5</sup>
- |freq_standard<sub>i</sub>| <= 10<sup>9</sup>
- |freq_signals<sub>i</sub>| <= 10<sup>9</sup>

**Output Format:**

Print `q` lines: each line should contain an integer representing the index of the standard frequency corresponding to the given signal. There is a code stub to handle I/O if you choose to use it.

**Sample Input 0:**

```
5 5    
7 1 12 9 15    
2 9 2000 13 4
```

**Sample Output 0:**

```
2
4
5
3
1
```

**My attempt:**

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.List;

    class Result1 {

/*
 * Complete the 'classifySignals' function below.
 *
 * The function is expected to return an INTEGER_ARRAY. The function accepts
 * following parameters: 1. INTEGER_ARRAY freq_standard 2. INTEGER_ARRAY
 * freq_signals
 */

public static List<Integer> classifySignals(List<Integer> freq_standard, List<Integer> freq_signals) {
    List<Integer> out = new ArrayList<>();
    int match = 0;
    int n = freq_standard.size();
    int q = freq_signals.size();
    List<Integer> freq_standard_unordered = new ArrayList<>(freq_standard);
    Collections.sort(freq_standard);

    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
        int signalToCompare = freq_signals.get(i);
        if (signalToCompare < freq_standard.get(0)) {
            match = freq_standard.get(0);
            out.add(freq_standard_unordered.indexOf(match) + 1);
            continue;
        }
        if (signalToCompare > freq_standard.get(n - 1)) {
            match = freq_standard.get(n - 1);
            out.add(freq_standard_unordered.indexOf(match) + 1);
            continue;
        }
        int j = 0, k = n, mid = 0;
        while (j < k) {
            mid = (j + k) / 2;

            if (freq_standard.get(mid) == signalToCompare) {
                match = freq_standard.get(mid);
                break;
            }

            if (signalToCompare < freq_standard.get(mid)) {
                match = mid - 1 > 0
                        ? findClosest(freq_standard.get(mid), freq_standard.get(mid - 1), signalToCompare)
                        : freq_standard.get(mid);
                k = mid;
            } else {
                match = mid + 1 < n
                        ? findClosest(freq_standard.get(mid + 1), freq_standard.get(mid), signalToCompare)
                        : freq_standard.get(mid);
                j = mid + 1;
            }

        }
        out.add(freq_standard_unordered.indexOf(match) + 1);
    }

    return out;
}

public static int findClosest(int n, int m, int target) {
    if (Math.abs(n - target) == Math.abs(m - target)) {
        return n;
    }
    if (Math.abs(n - target) > Math.abs(m - target)) {
        return m;
    } else {
        return n;
    }
}

    }

    public class GFG {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String[] firstMultipleInput = bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+$", "").split(" ");

    int n = Integer.parseInt(firstMultipleInput[0]);

    int q = Integer.parseInt(firstMultipleInput[1]);

    String[] fTemp = bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+$", "").split(" ");

    List<Integer> f = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int fItem = Integer.parseInt(fTemp[i]);
        f.add(fItem);
    }

    String[] FTemp = bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+$", "").split(" ");

    List<Integer> F = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
        int FItem = Integer.parseInt(FTemp[i]);
        F.add(FItem);
    }

    List<Integer> ans = Result1.classifySignals(f, F);

    System.out.println(ans);

}
}
```

Comment: Post the problem statement in the question, don't make people go to some different site.

Comment: sure, updated accordingly

Comment: A comment about performance in general, unrelated to your proposed algorithm. Your application needlessly uses many, many megabytes of RAM. It does not need to read whole lines at a time; it does not need to put all the "signal" numbers into a list before it starts classifying them; and it doesn't need to put all the output into a list before it prints it. You can read all the standard numbers into a pre-allocated array of int (more efficient than List of Integer). You can then read one signal number at a time, printing the nearest standard number before reading the next one.

Comment: I made the comment above because it's not just the algorithm that can affect performance. Some applications need to run on machines with small amounts of RAM, and if you use much more memory than necessary, it can adversely affect performance.

Comment: I couldnt understand, why we get a -1 for a question asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
out.add(freq_standard_unordered.indexOf(match) + 1);
```

Which is finding the index of the match that takes O(n) in the worst case in itself. This is also inside a loop which makes it O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Your idea of binary search is correct. But, while sorting, you can't lose indices of elements, which is what actually made you do `out.add(freq_standard_unordered.indexOf(match) + 1);`

To avoid this, you can make a class(or have a 2D array) which stores value as well as index and do binary search on them accordingly. This way, you can correctly judge actual index of an element in it's original ordering. Below is how I did it(note that it can have some unnecessary checks, but you get the idea of the overall strategy anyway)

**Snippet:**

```
class Result {
    static class Data{
        int val,actual_index;
        Data(int val,int index){
            this.val = val;
            this.actual_index = index;
        }
    }
    public static List<Integer> classifySignals(List<Integer> freq_standard, List<Integer> freq_signals) {
        Data[] d = new Data[freq_standard.size()];
        for(int i=0;i<d.length;++i) d[i] = new Data(freq_standard.get(i),i);
        Arrays.sort(d,new Comparator<Data>(){
            public int compare(Data d1,Data d2){
                if(d1.val <= d2.val) return -1;
                return 1; // not doing d1.val - d2.val to avoid overflows(although irrelevant here)
            }
        });    

        int size = freq_signals.size();        
        List<Integer> ans = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0;i < size; ++i){
            int ele = freq_signals.get(i);
            int index = getClosest(d,freq_standard,ele);
            ans.add(index + 1);
        }

        return ans;
    }

    private static int getClosest(Data[] d,List<Integer> freq_standard,int ele){
        int index = -1;
        int low = 0,high = d.length - 1;
        while(low <= high){
            int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
            if(d[mid].val == ele) return d[mid].actual_index;
            if(d[mid].val > ele){
                if(index == -1 || Math.abs(freq_standard.get(d[index].actual_index) - ele) > Math.abs(d[mid].val - ele)) index = mid;
                high = mid - 1;
            }else{
                if(index == -1 || Math.abs(freq_standard.get(d[index].actual_index) - ele) > Math.abs(d[mid].val - ele)) index = mid;
                low = mid + 1;
            }
        }

        if(index + 1 < d.length){
            int current_closest = freq_standard.get(d[index].actual_index);
            int next_closest = freq_standard.get(d[index + 1].actual_index);
            if(Math.abs(ele - current_closest) == Math.abs(ele - next_closest)) return d[index + 1].actual_index;
        }

        return d[index].actual_index;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant solution, I am going to test this tomorrow to check what are the implications of using a class & array of n objects. maybe it might hurt me for memory now

Comment: @code-match That's fine. Memory won't be an issue here.

Answer (score 2):

Try this bro,it took 0.1s in my computer to test data set of 1 Lakh numbers.
its just a testing logic,if it goes properly,you can have some optimization on it.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class a4_test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // sampleTest1
        int[] freq_standard = new int[]{1, 2};
        int[] freq_signals = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        // sampleTest2
        freq_standard = new int[]{7, 1, 12, 9, 15};
        freq_signals = new int[]{2, 9, 2000, 13, 4};

//         randomArray For Testing
        freq_standard = randomArray((int) Math.pow(10,5),(int) Math.pow(10,9));
        freq_signals = randomArray((int) Math.pow(10,5),(int) Math.pow(10,9));
        System.out.println("standard:" + Arrays.toString(freq_standard));
        System.out.println("signals" + Arrays.toString(freq_signals));

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int[] classify = classifySignals(freq_standard, freq_signals);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("time cost:" + (end - start));
        System.out.println("classifyArray:" + Arrays.toString(classify));
    }

    // mainMethod
    public static int[] classifySignals(int[] freq_standard, int[] freq_signals) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = freq_sort(freq_standard);

        Arrays.sort(freq_standard); // there are better sort algorithms for a lower time complexity,fix me~

        // a caching classifyArray,should be construct with 'n'
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>((int) Math.pow(10, 5));
        for (int freq_signal : freq_signals) {
            int index = findTarget(freq_standard, freq_signal);
            list.add(map.get(freq_standard[index]));    // get original index in original freq_standard[]
        }

        // truly classifyArray，the problem asked a int[] to return
        int[] classifyArray = new int[list.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < classifyArray.length; i++) {
            classifyArray[i] = list.get(i);
        }
        return classifyArray;
    }

    // record the original index of freq_standard
    public static Map<Integer, Integer> freq_sort(int[] freq_standard) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < freq_standard.length; i++) {
            map.put(freq_standard[i], i + 1);   // ok,the problem defined 1 is the begin of array index
        }
        return map;
    }

    // find targetIndex
    private static int findTarget(int[] array, int targetNum) {
        // boundaryCheck
        if (targetNum <= array[0]) {
            return 0;
        } else if (targetNum >= array[array.length - 1]) {
            return array.length - 1;
        }
        // binary search
        int left = 0, right = array.length - 1;
        for (; right - left > 1; ) {
            int pivot = (right + left) / 2;
            int middle = array[pivot];
            if (targetNum == middle) {
                return pivot;
            }
            if (targetNum > middle) {
                left = pivot + 1;
            } else {
                right = pivot - 1;
            }
        }
        int index = targetNum < ((array[right] + array[left]) * 1.0 / 2) ?
                left : right;
//        System.out.println("target:" + targetNum + ",leftV:" + array[left] + ",rightV:" + array[right] + ",indexV:" + array[index]);
        return index;
    }

    // generate random array to test
    public static int[] randomArray(int maxMember, int maxValue) {
        int[] randomArray = new int[maxMember];
        for (int i = 0; i < maxMember; i++) {
            randomArray[i] = (int) (Math.random() * maxValue);
        }
        return randomArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you doing the equidistant absolute value check?

Comment: use binary search to get the closest left and right one in function findTarget()

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Perhaps while taking the values from test data files there would be more overhead than simply taking hard-coded array

Comment: @TenkFish Just curious how you deal with absolute difference checks because I find it hard to follow your code. Say, we have element `4` at hand, you have 2 closest elements `1` and `7`, how do you decide which one to pick in your search code. This problem wants us to pick a higher value which is `7` in this case.

Comment: you could use hard-coded array to test both solution if The Loading cost much more than the logic

Comment: here is the code: int index = targetNum < ((array[right] + array[left]) * 1.0 / 2) ? left : right;

Comment: by the way，i only counted the logic time cost not include generating randomly array，you could use `System.currentTimeMillis()`to get millisTimePoint before/after Loading and Logic block to collect time cost

Comment: @vivek_23  is that still bothering you? well，we hava `1` as left,`7` right,and `4` to locate: is `4` < `(1 + 7) / 2 = 4` ? false.
So wo can pick the right one `7`.

Comment: @TenkFish Nice. I get it now. +1 . I seem to have done some redundant checks as I suspected. Can you please cross check with this link https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/hackerrank-women-technologists-codesprint-2019/challenges/signal-classification/problem ?

Comment: @vivek_23 yeah , checked before i answering this question。its hard for me understanding all the rules described and to submit one formal code。you could use above logics if you wish : )，that's 100% ok

Comment: @TenkFish Your submission got me a wrong answer https://imgur.com/a/xvGGTJd